# Checking that a function satisfies a differential equation

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Prove that this function proves the relation written next to it.
$y=\sin(x)+a\cdot \cos(x)$  ...the relation is $ y\cdot \sin(x) +y'\cdot \cos(x)=1$

I tried using logarithmic differentiation but nothing...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need logarithmic differentation for this. You have that $y =\sin x + a \cos x$. First of all, you should find $y'$, which I assume you know how to do. Now multiply $y$ by $\sin x$, $y'$ by $\cos x$ and add them up.

I'll help you with the first one: $y \sin x = \sin^2 x + a \cos x \sin x$. After finding $y'$, multiply that by $\cos x$ and add it to what we just got. The result should be $1$.